# System doesn't boot GRUB/Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 16.04, boot-repair, windows-10

After installing Ubuntu via a USB and restarting the computer it only boots windows. I checked on the BIOS and Ubuntu doesn't appear.
I can boot into Ubuntu using the USB: it boots the menu: try Ubuntu, install Ubuntu, etc. then I press Esc and it shows the GRUB terminal, then I enter exit and the boot management appears. There, I can select Ubuntu which actually appears as a booting option (It doesn't in BIOS) and it runs the GRUB where I can select either Ubuntu or Windows.

I tried the boot repair inside Ubuntu and this is the report link:
http://paste2.org/ykpn6NvZ

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
=> No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
=> No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
```

So you don't have boot loader on the root partition of your hard drive and

```
Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name                          Flags
1      1049kB  473MB  472MB   ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
2      473MB   578MB  105MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, esp
3      578MB   595MB  16.8MB                  Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
4      595MB   689GB  689GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
5      689GB   742GB  52.3GB  ext4
6      742GB   750GB  8518MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

boot flag is set to the second fat32 partition.

```
Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     923647     921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2      923648    1128447     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3     1128448    1161215      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     1161216 1346364490 1345203275 641.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  1346365440 1448511487  102146048  48.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  1448511488 1465147391   16635904     8G Linux swap
```

Suggested idea: install grub loader on /dev/sda

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

using Boot-Repair advanced menu, place the boot flag to /dev/sda  (i.e. grub and boot flag should be set on the same partition).

[image: boot-repair boot flag]

Comment: The boot flag option doesn't appear on my grub options. Is ther any other way to change it?

Comment: @JosepPlanells  While googling for it, i found that looks like there is [no need to change the boot flag](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1850805) for linux. (If you still need it `sudo sfdisk -A2 /dev/sda` will do it)  Installing grub on /dev/sda should be enough. Read please [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)